# How do I declare constants for Items in my ListBox?

Tags: vb.net

[image: Coding]

[image: Design]

I don't know why also it is showing a red line for the coding

Answer (score 0):

You can't have spaces in identifiers. Either use camel-casing, e.g. `thisIsCamelCasing`, or use underscores, e.g. `THIS_USES_UNDERSCORES`.

Comment: But then how do I connect D_Hotel_SeriIskandar with the Listbox Item?

Comment: That's got nothing to do with the question you asked. The issue you asked about here was declaring a constant and that question has been answered. If you have issues with a `ListBox` then that is a different question so you need to post it as a different question, with all and only the information relevant to that question.

Comment: That said, a `ListBox` displays values, not identifiers, i.e. it will display the value you assign to a variable or constant, not the name of the variable or constant. If you expect to display the name of a hotel then that name must be assigned somewhere as text, not an identifier. This is basic programming and not something for us to teach you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an enum which holds the integer representation of the hotels and a dictionary with `key = enum` and `value = string representation of the hotel`.
The dictionary serves as the datasource of the ListBox. Make sure to create a bindingsource too, otherwise the binding will fail.

```
Public Class Form1
   Enum HotelsEnum
      D_Hotel_Seri_Iskander = 100
      Hotel_Putra = 200
      Hamriz_Hotel = 300
   End Enum

   Private hotelById As New Dictionary(Of HotelsEnum, String) From {
                                    {HotelsEnum.D_Hotel_Seri_Iskander, "D Hotel Seri Iskander"},
                                    {HotelsEnum.Hotel_Putra, "Hotel Putra"},
                                    {HotelsEnum.Hamriz_Hotel, "Hamriz Hotel"}}


   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       ListBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(hotelById, Nothing)
       ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
       ListBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
  End Sub

End Class
```